# Question Regarding Microsoft Excel Problem Solving Problem - Why is the "2" in "$B2" also considered an absolute reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently taking a Coursera course titled, "Everyday Excel, Part I" on Coursera. I was working on a quiz in the course and came across the following question:

**Question 1**
What will happen in the following spreadsheet setup if we: 1) Press Enter, 2) copy the formula in cell B3 using Ctrl-C (or Copy), and 3) paste the formula into cell A3?  What value will result in cell A3?  NOTE that this question is NOT asking for the value in cell B3!

[Imaged referenced in Excel Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDOeS.jpg)

The choices are:
A. 11
B. 9
C. 3
D. 5
E. 6

I selected Choice D. 5, which is incorrect. The explanation for why this answer was as follows:

"I​ncorrect.  In cell B3, the C$3 and $B2 are both mixed references.  If we copy the formula in cell B3 and paste it in cell A3, then we will move all relative references in that formula over to the left one column.  But, any relative row references will remain the same.  Thus, C$3 in the copied formula will become B$3, but $B2 will remain B$2 since it has an absolute column reference.  Therefore, the formula in cell A3 will be “=B$3-$B2”.  The value in cell B3 will be 5 (7 – 2).  Thus, the value in cell A3 will equal 5-2 = 3."

The correct answer is 3. However, is there a reason why the 2 in "$B2" is also an absolute reference? I thought that only portions of the reference that came after the "$" sign were considered absolute references. Any input regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: `$B2` is a semi-absolute reference. So the way you phrase your question is wrong; instead you are wondering why the reference stays the same when dragging the formula left or right I suppose.

Comment: In short column cannot change because of the $ and row did not change as you stayed on row 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the dollar sign ($) before the column ($C1) then no matter what the column stays the same, meaning if you shift it one column to the right, it's going to stay **$C1**, but if you shift it one row downwards, it's going to change its row **$C2**.

If you put the dollar sign ($) before the row (C$1) then no matter what the row stays the same, meaning if you shift it one row downwards, it's going to stay **C$1**, but if you shift it one column to the right, it's going to change its column **D$2**.

So, in your example the reason why **$B2** doesn't change is because the column is fixed and also there is no change in rows, so there is no reason to expect the column or the row to change, since whenever you change columns, rows won't change and vice versa.